# Run a shell script as a different user

Tags: linux, debian, shell, scripting, suid

What's a good way of running a shell script as a different user. I'm using Debian etch, and I know which user I want to impersonate.

If I was doing it manually, I would do:

```
su postgres
./backup_db.sh /tmp/test
exit
```

Since I want to automate the process, I need a way to run backup_db.sh as postgres (inheriting the environment, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

To run your script as another user as one command, run:

```
/bin/su -c "/path/to/backup_db.sh /tmp/test" - postgres

Breaking it down:
 /bin/su : switch user
 -c "/path/to..." : command to run
 - : option to su, make it a login session (source profile for the user)
 postgres : user to become
```

I recommend always using full paths in scripts like this - you can't always guarantee that you'll be in the right directory when you su (maybe someone changed the homedir on you, who knows).  I also always use the full path to su (/bin/su) because I'm paranoid.  It's possible someone can edit your path and cause you to use a compromised version of su.

Comment: It will always require me type in password ? How can get round it ?

Comment: It will always require you to type in a password if you are running the command as a non-root user.  If you want to avoid the password, you can configure sudo to allow that.  HOWEVER - configuring sudo to allow a user to run su allows them to become any user.  I would suggest creating a script for your command, setting the script permissions to 700 and owned by root, then configuring sudo to allow a user to run that single script.

Comment: I believe - while this answer might work for the OP - it is not entirely correct. To my knowledge, using both `-` (or `--login`) together with `--command, -c` doesn't actually start a login session, because `-c` always forces a non-login shell.

Comment: Note: for portability, the `- postgress` should appear at the end of the command.  From the man page: `When - is used, it must be specified before any username. For portability it is recommended to use it as last option, before any username. The other forms (-l and --login) do not have this restriction.`

Comment: will this work on `www-data` user ?

Comment: Yes, it will work for any user.

Answer (score 30):

If the target user to run has nologin shelll defined, then you can use the -s option to specify the shell:

```
/bin/su -s /bin/bash -c '/path/to/your/script' testuser
```

See the following question:
[run script as user who has nologin shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/351046/run-script-as-user-who-has-nologin-shell)

Answer (score 10):

To automate this on a schedule you could put it in the user's crontab.  Cron jobs won't get the full environment though, but it it might be better to put all the env variables you need in the script itself anyways.

To edit the user's crontab:

```
sudo crontab -u postgres -e
```

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 4):

This should be an informative read -- [**setuid on shell scripts**](https://web.archive.org/web/20150707023141/http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html)

If you run **su** with a "**`- username`**" argument sequence, it will make a login shell for the user to give the same environment as the user. Usually, used to quickly execute your script with your home environment from a different login.

Comment: This can be useful, if you need to perform a series of actions. But bear in mind that most system service accounts shouldn't have valid home paths and shells.

Answer (score 2):

Try the su manpage:

su -c script_run_as_postgres.sh - postgres

Alernately, you could use sudo to allow you to run just that comman as postgres without a password.  It takes some setup in your /etc/sudoers, though.

Answer (score 2):

The "su -c ... " method posted by others is a good one.  For automation, you could add the script to the crontab of the user you need it to execute as.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

> sudo -u postgres script_run_as_postgres.sh

Comment: If you need a login shell, you can run this command with -i

Answer (score 1):

If the user already has an entry to sudo and you don't know superuser's password then you can try following: This one restarts the postgres initialized at /data/my-db/pgsql/9.6/data

```
sudo su - postgres -c "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_ctl -D /data/my-db/pgsql/9.6/data -l /var/log/pgsql.log restart"
```