# How to call a bash script from another script, as a different user?

Tags: linux, debian, bash, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a shell script as a different user](https://serverfault.com/questions/44400/run-a-shell-script-as-a-different-user)

While writing scripts to automate the intialisation of SVN mirror repositories ([svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication)), I again ran into problems trying to **start another script with another user's privileges**.

```
#!/bin/sh
# This outer script is always run with root privileges ("sudo create-repo.sh")

# Create repository, set privileges, etc
[...]

# Set up remote mirror; this works fine! (SSH key authentication)
ssh svnsync@anotherserver /var/lib/svn/init-mirror.sh $REPO

# Set up local mirror as "svnsync" user
# ???
```

**How can I call the other script, on the same machine, as a different user?** Note that the outer script is always executed as root so `su`'ing as anyuser should not be a problem.

I tried something like:

```
su svnsync; /path/to/init-mirror.sh $REPO; exit
```

and get weird results. How are you supposed to do it? When it's so easy remotely it's probably *possible* locally, right? (For now, let's pretend running the outer script as the same "svnsync" user is not an option.)

I think the question title sucks, so please help me reword it if you can.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/44400/run-a-shell-script-as-a-different-user

Comment: Yeah, that was it, thanks! This can be closed. (But while it's open, if you want to post an answer I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [Run a shell script as a different user](https://serverfault.com/questions/44400/run-a-shell-script-as-a-different-user) .  I think you can close it yourself?

Comment: I could *delete* it, but I'd rather have it closed as dupe (so that the slightly differently worded versions match more google searches)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.