# run script as another user from a root script with no tty stdin

Tags: linux, centos, shell, su, daemontools

Using CentOs, I want to run a script as user 'training' as a system service. I use daemontools to monitor the process, which needs a launcher script that is run as root and has no tty standard in.

Below I give my five different attempts which all fail.

1. :

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   exec >> /var/log/training_service.log 2>&1
   setuidgid training training_command
   ```

   This last line is not good enough since for training_command, we need environment for trqaining user to be set.
2. :

   ```
   su - training -c 'training_command'
   ```

   This looks like it ([Run a shell script as a different user](https://serverfault.com/questions/44400/run-a-shell-script-as-a-different-user)) but gives '`standard in must be tty`' as su making sure tty is present to potentially accept password. I know I could make this disappear by modifying /etc/sudoers (a la https://superuser.com/questions/119376/bash-su-script-giving-an-error-standard-in-must-be-a-tty) but i am reluctant and unsure of consequences.
3. :

   ```
   sudo -u training -i bash -c 'source $HOME/.bashrc; training_command'
   ```

   A variation on the same theme: '`sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`'
4. :

   ```
   runuser - training -c 'training_command'
   ```

   This one gives `runuser: cannot set groups: Connection refused`. I found no sense or resolution to this error.
5. :

   ```
   ssh -p100 training@localhost 'source $HOME/.bashrc; training_command'
   ```

   This one is more of a joke to show desparation. Even this one fails with `Host key verification failed.` (the host key IS in known_hosts, etc).

**Note: all of 2,3,4 work as they should if I run the wrapper script from a root shell.** problems only occur if the system service monitor (daemontools) launches it (no tty terminal I guess).

I am stuck. Is this something so hard to achieve?

I appreciate all insight and guidance to best practice.

(this has also been posted on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/434235/script-calling-script-as-other-user)

Answer (score 6):

You will need to disable the `requiretty` setting in `/etc/sudoers` for `root`. Add the following line via `visudo`:

```
Defaults:root !requiretty
```

You will also need the following line in `/etc/sudoers` so `root` can do everything (this should be enabled by default, but check to be sure):

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Then you can do the following:

```
sudo -u training /path/to/training_command
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be essentially a special case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe); we can use `script -c` to fake a tty. The only problem is that I can't get that trick to work directly with `su` for some reason, and `sudo` is a bit ugly if you really have to source `~/.bashrc` before `training_command`. Try:

```
echo password | script -c "sudo su - training -c training_command"
```

Comment: I use `script -c "su username scriptFile.sh"` with success with [a user that does not need a password to su to another user](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113754/allow-user1-to-su-user2-without-password)

Answer (score 0):

Choose the first one and set the environment variables you need.

If you already use daemontools then you do not create or mess with the log files manually.
Daemontools does that job for you.

This is the script for the applicatoin run script

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2>&1
exec setuidgid training sh -c 'YOURVARIABLE=yourvalue exec training_command'
```

Then you create a `log` directory run script with its own runscript.

Refer to this entry for setting up a log:
http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/faq/create.html#runlog

Comment: Thanks Tamas. But. Setuidgid only sets the owner of the process not the environment. I really do need to be training user with its environment to run the command. your solution of putting 'YOURVARIABLE=yourvalue' does not do justice to this. I need to replicate exactly what a login shell sets and do not want to rely on knowing anything about the command beyond that. I can't believe there is no solution to this simple problem and how come noone ever ran into it. I think I am missing something...

Comment: @ViktorTrón: Log in as training.

Execute the command

`set >training.set`

Log out.

edit cstamas' script above to insert the line

`. /home/training/training.set`

right before the last line.  It should set every environment variable that was set by the login process to the same value it had when you logged in manually.  You may need to edit that file and remove one or two variables that might mislead your program, but you probably don't even need to do that.

Comment: You want to also unset variables that are not part of the training environment. I'd use "su training /bin/sh -c ". <set up environment>; runcommand".  That works for me for setting up system services.

Answer (score 0):

Plagiarising my answer here: [Starting a script as another user](https://serverfault.com/questions/585751/starting-a-script-as-another-user)

You could use start-stop-daemon something like this:

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon --background --start --exec /path/to/training.sh --user training --pidfile=/path/to/training.pid --make-pidfile
```

where training.sh is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec >> /var/log/training_service.log 2>&1
source /home/training/.bashrc
training_command
```

Answer (score 0):

Under SSH, you can run command `foo.sh` in normal user:

```
$ ssh normal_user@1.2.3.4 bash /path/to/foo.sh
```

if one of `foo.sh`'s command need root privilege, for example, `netstat`, wrap it within `su` command like this (replace original raw `netstat -tunple`):

```
su -c "netstat -tunpl" root
```

and run `foo.sh` like this:

```
$ ssh -t normal_user@1.2.3.4 bash /path/to/foo.sh
```

This will prompt tow password, the first is for `normal_user`, and the second is for `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Run your command with SSH.

1. make ssh key configuration to login without password for other user. Here is a tutorial for this purpose: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2
2. Run the command with ssh:
   ssh -l training -i key_file "training_command"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u training training_command > /var/log/training_service.log 2>&1
```

If this fails, please post the output of **/var/log/training_service.log**.

Comment: thanks Alex. Alas, sudo does not set the environment only if used with -i option. plus it still complains about missing tty if invoked by supervise. see my edited question including a variant of this.

Comment: You are right. Then `su - training --session-command=training_command >> /var/log/training_service.log 2>&1` should do it.

Comment: Thanks Alex but as said su gives 'standard in must be a tty' if called from script.

Comment: I tried the above on a RHEL 6.2 box (before recommending it) as a cron script, and it worked perfectly. You tried it and it didn't work?